# Cannot center jQuery UI-styled Radio Buttons

Tags: html, jquery-ui, radio-button

I had a set of radio buttons that were inline. I have since converted them to jQuery UI buttons with this line of code:

```
$("input:radio").button();
```

Now, they are all looking nice, but they are still aligned to the left. I can't fix this problem. I tried even using `<center>`, and everything in between, but it didn't center it as I wanted.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div style="display: <?php echo $visible; ?>;">
        <form action="php/ratingsPost.php" method="POST" id="ratingsPost">
                      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="rate" value="1" id="1" onChange="javascript:$('#ratingsPost').submit()"/>
                      <label for="1">1</label>
                      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="rate" value="2" id="2" onChange="javascript:$('#ratingsPost').submit()"/>
                      <label for="2">2</label>
                      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="rate" value="3" id="3" onChange="javascript:$('#ratingsPost').submit()"/>
                      <label for="3">3</label>
                      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="rate" value="4" id="4" onChange="javascript:$('#ratingsPost').submit()"/>
                      <label for="4">4</label>
                      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="rate" value="5" id="5" onChange="javascript:$('#ratingsPost').submit()"/>
                      <label for="5">5</label>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Any help?

Comment: could you put up a jsfiddle example of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According with [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) (last tab), you can specify a different theme for your JQueryUI components.

The whole radio buttons should be similar to this:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Button Label</span>
</button>
```

All what you need is overwrite classes for your own design using personal CSS stylesheet. For example:

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text{
    // personal style
}
```

Anyways, a little code using [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com) or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) as JohnP said could be nice to get a better view of your problem. Happy codding!